# How to add Empty Activity in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm currently learning mobile app development and I can't seem to figure out why I can't create a new Activity in Android Studio.

[image]

I tried installing Android 6.0 Marshmallow which is API level 23.
[image]

I also checked the version in SDK tools and it's 30.0.4.
My question what is the minSdk? And how do I change it to >=16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

minSdk is the starting version which your app can support, you can change the sdk version in app level build.gradle [image]